# Include JavaScript files to the document head with php

Tags: javascript, php, html, import

I'm creating a blog where I included `header.php`(Header, included in every page). Header contains a section where all the scripts (Scripts that will need in every pages) will be included.

header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <!-- Scripts Section -->
      <script src="example01.js"></script>
      <script src="example02.js"></script>
      <title>Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <p>Blog</p>
```

But in a specific page, I've to include a specific script (file.js named).

index.php

```
<?php
  include('header.php');
  importjs('file.js'); /* Any Function To Import JavaScript*/
?>
```

If I include the JavaScript file here then it'll be included in body not the scripts section in the header. I don't know how to create that function. So please tell me how to create that function. create function in header.php and please first include the header before using function.

Thank You

Comment: Are all the javascript files that you include in the `header.php` script hardcoded or dynamically generated somehow?

Comment: simply remove `importjs('file.js');` and add `<script src="file.js"></script>` after the line ?> in this particular php file (Note: you can have multiple <script>....</script> in a single page)

Comment: It doesn't matter if the script is in the body or the head, it makes no difference in practice

Comment: Leave the ending `head` tag out of the header.php file, and add it on every page file instead. That way you can add lines to the head section.

Comment: Why don't you use the function approach that you had in your last question? It works much better... see my [updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73875887/9473764) to your old question

Comment: @ADyson, I want to create a professional website. So I want it to be clean and simple code. Because whenever someone see my site's source code it will look pretty

Comment: I don't think anyone would be perturbed  to find a script tag in the body, it's not at all unusual. But you can also use Nick's idea, it's a good one.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should to write your line code like this example:

```php
<?php int a; ?> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="file.js" /> 
<?php int b; ?>
```

Comment: What is it, actually?

Comment: it similar with Ken Lee comment. We need to separate the <script /> line from the <?php ?>

Because of <script /> doesn't work in the <?php ?> line.

Thank you